# find_or_create_by in the ruby jsonb column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jsonb, ruby-on-rails-6.1

are we have `find_or_create_by` for jsonb in Ruby?
I wanna get an item that has a `something` title

`{ title: {en: 'something', de: 'something' }`

instead of

```rb
Model.where(sanitize_sql("title->> '#{I18n.locale}' ILIKE ?"), 'something')
```

Answer (score 1):

No, we do not have that functionality.

For PostgreSQL databases, Rails yields to the PostgreSQL functions and operators for JSON and JSONB and does not layer any access methods for those

- [Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb)
- [Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

And in general, [`ActiveRecord::Type::Json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Type/Json.html) can only serialize and deserialize.